# JIRA rest API to get list of user based on created date

Tags: jira-rest-api

Iam using ajax call to get the list of user and issue created at specific date.

```
http://server/issues/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=name&project=projkey&created=2016-08-16.
```

But iam getting all issue of user irrespective of date.

Can anyone correct my query.

Answer (score 0):

Equality ("created=") forces an exact match. Try using a range:

...&created>2016-08-15&created<2016-08-17

Answer (score 0):

Try using `+AND+` instead of `&`. I had a similar problem, it seems that `&` sometimes means `OR`

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. 
This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.